# reg expressions in c# -- difficult when I combine all my conditions

Tags: c#

```
    public static string GetData(string subjectLine)
    {
        // Define the regular expression pattern. 

        string pattern = "";
        string returnString = "Error";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(subjectLine);

        if (matches.Count >= 1)
        {
            return matches[0].Value;
        }
        return returnString;

    }
```

I have written the above method to get the matching pattern string. I understand individually all the pattern matching characters. But I am failing when I put all my conditions together. Removed my test pattern data since I am not getting the result when I put all my conditions together.

Here is the pattern I am looking for `[stringData1-OnlyNumericData1-OnlyNumericData2]`.  The max size limit for `stringData1` is 10. At least one characters should be there in `stringData1`, `OnlyNumericData1` and `OnlyNumericData2`.

Cases

1. Here is the test subject line `[testData1-12345-678]` and `test-1213-778]`. Returns only `[testData1-12345-678]` and `[` is missing in second occurrence.
2. Here is the test subject line `[testData1-test12345-678Test]` and `test-1213-778]`. Returns nothing because `OnlyNumericData1` & `OnlyNumericData2` are not numeric.

Comment: What if "stringData1" contains a dash or right bracket?

Comment: "stringData1" should not contain dash or right bracket or left bracket. If it contains such data it is considered as bad data and the pattern match should not happen.

Comment: Mmmhm.  So what are the patterns you're using to filter each part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex test, executed on your entire question only gives me 2 matches:

```
        string strRegex = @"\[\w{1,10}-[\d]+?-[\d]+\]";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
        string strTargetString = @"I have written the above method to get the matching pattern string. I understand individually all the pattern matching characters. But I am failing when I put all my conditions together. Removed my test pattern data since I am not getting the result when I put all my conditions together." + "\n\n" + @"Here is the pattern I am looking for [stringData1-OnlyNumericData1-OnlyNumericData2]. The max size limit for stringData1 is 10. At least one characters should be there in stringData1, OnlyNumericData1 and OnlyNumericData2." + "\n\n" + @"Cases" + "\n\n" + @"Here is the test subject line [testData1-12345-678] and test-1213-778]. Returns only [testData1-12345-678] and [ is missing in second occurrence." + "\n\n" + @"Here is the test subject line [testData1-test12345-678Test] and test-1213-778]. Returns nothing because OnlyNumericData1 & OnlyNumericData2 are not numeric.";

        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
        {
            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
                // Add your code here
            }
        }
```

Btw: [this](http://regexhero.net/tester/) is a good site for online dotnet regex testing

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetData(string subjectLine)
{
    //im not sure if you want to include numeric in the stringData1 part
    //replace [A-z\d] with [A-z] to accept only letters for stringData1
    var result = Regex.Match(subjectLine, @"\[[A-z\d]{1,10}-\d+-\d+\]");
    return result.Success ? result.Value : "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having luck with this one:

```
\A[\][\s\w-]{1,10}-[0-9]+-[0-9]+[\]]
```